# Reducing data memory when values are identical for many keys C#

Tags: c#, bigdata

I have a lot of data in the following text form:

```
    4c5c,6c4h,486,30
    4c5c,6c5h,486,30
    4c5c,6c6h,458,0
    4c5c,6c7h,648,9
    4c5c,6c8h,648,9
    3sTs,QsKs,182,0
    3sTs,QsAs,182,0
    3sTs,KsAs,743,0
    3sJs,4s5s,495,0
    3sJs,4s6s,625,0
    3sJs,4s7s,739,0
    3sJs,4s8s,739,0
    3sJs,4s9s,739,0
    3sJs,4sTs,739,0
    3sJs,4sQs,182,0
    3sJs,4sKs,739,0
    3sJs,4sAs,625,0
    3sJs,5s6s,625,0
    3sJs,5s7s,739,0
    3sJs,5s8s,739,0
```

On each line, the first 2 terms represent a key, and the second 2 terms represent values.
e.g.
KEY: 3sJs,5s8s
VALUE: 739,0

I have over 14 billion of these lines and have been storing them in a Dictionary for fast access. This is problematic as there is around 250GB of text data which requires a lot of memory when stored in a Dictionary. However, I've noticed many of the Values are identical for multiple keys. Is there some alternative way to Dictionary in which I can store this data with reduced memory requirement to leverage the fact that many values are repeated?
I've not used a database with a C# program before but have done a little postgres - is sqlite my best/only sensible option and will it reduce my application size to a manageable size for distribution?

Comment: Is this text data static? I doubt you can reduce the size by putting it in a sqlite database. Can any constraints be defined? For example length of the keys, min and max values.

Comment: The keys are playing cards, e.g. 3s is 3 of spades. The data will never change. The values are ints no bigger than 990.

Comment: Then I would put the data in a 5 dimensional array of shorts. the first 4 dimesnsions are the card index (from 0 to 51 - assign the cards a numeric value), the 5th is value 0 or 1. This reduces your data to approx. 28 MB. And this is also the fastets way to access them by the keys.

Comment: By the way, I don't play cards, so I don't know how many cards there are. I assumed 52 by searching in google. If so, you can't have 14 billion rows without repeating some keys. The maximum would be 52 * 52 * 52 * 52 = 7,311,616. So something is wrong here...

Comment: thats because there is an additional key made up of 3 more cards. Currently these are in seperate files so I didn't mention that. Could you give me an example of the 5-dim array of shorts and how to access the data. I'm not quite sure what you mean but it sounds promising

Comment: By adding 3 more dimensions you would end up with ≈ 4GB of data. So without knowing, how those 3 more cards are involved, I don't know if it's still practicable

Comment: And what about keys? Are there duplicates on the left and right? If so check string interning to store it only once in memory https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.intern?view=net-5.0

Comment: Additionaly you can encode key as `long` (left and right together). Each `long` occupies only 4 bytes. While string of 9 chars (if you store left and right as single string) occupies 26 bytes (each character is 2 bytes + 8 bytes reference on 64 bit machine)

Comment: Sorry, `long` is 8 bytes

Comment: You could go further and encode each key as an `int32`. Where the first three bytes represent each card number(0-13)and the last byte represents all three cards suits (0-3). Also if these values are calculated some way from the key you may want to consider not storing them at all and calculating on the fly.

Comment: Have you tried interning your strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the constraints mentioned in your comments, you could put the shown sample data in a 5-dimensional array. You asked for a sample, here is it. I'll take the first row from your sample data:

> 4c5c,6c4h,486,30

First, you'll have to assign numeric values to the cards. It's up to you how you number them between 0 and 51. For simplicity I'll use

```
4c = 0
5c = 1
6c = 2
4h = 3
```

The array would be something like this:

```
var data = new short [52, 52, 52, 52, 2];
```

The first four dimensions represent the keys (card numbers form 0 to 51), the 5th the index of the values (0 or 1).
Then you can access your array like this (here I'll set the values from the first row in your sample data):

```
data[0, 1, 2, 3, 0] = 486;
data[0, 1, 2, 3, 1] = 30;
```

If there are card combinations that are invalid or unwanted, simply don't put them in the array (all elements are by default initialized to 0). This array will have a fixed size of 29,246,464 bytes. Accessing the array elements by the card numbers is the fastest possible way. But as I wrote in my comments, this is only for your presented data structure. It is unclear how other three cards are related, this array can build up only your presented data sample. Still hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what your value is. How small could you encode your values? I'm going to assume that you can pack them into 4 bytes.

So your key is a text string describing 4 playing cards. So your possible key space is at most `52^4 ~= 7.3e6`. Out of all possible keys, what fraction will have a value? Is it close to all of them?

Rather than using a text string to represent your key, I would instead assign a number to each card (0-51). Then build an `Int32` key `=k1 + k2*52 + k3*(52^2) + k4*(52^3)`.

If you are storing a value for most keys, then you don't need a dictionary. You can just use an array of length `52^4`. This way you never need to allocate any memory for the keys themselves. Requiring only `4bytes * 52^4 ~= 28MB` of ram.

Then to store this array on disk, I would save it in a zip archive. Which should compress well, if you have many similar values.

You might wish to partitioning this data into multiple sections, so you don't have to decompress the entire structure into memory. But that would depend on how you expect to use this data at runtime.

Comment: Hi Jeremy. You mention storing the array to disk in a zip archive. Would this mean writing the array out as text strings and compressing the text? Or is there some way to write out and compress ints taking less storage memory than strings?

Comment: Files are just byte arrays, you'll need a way to pack / unpack your values into an array then write it. eg https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.bitconverter.trywritebytes?view=net-5.0 ?